# Can I use vuetify tags inside blade laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-blade

For example, I have a `vuetify` element `<v-card></v-card>`, can I just use the `v-card` inside the `home.blade.php`?

```
<v-card>
 <h2 class="mb-3">{{ __('Welcome back, ') . $user->name }}</h2>
</v-card>
```

Comment: can? yes, bad practice? primarily opinion based

Comment: Also, the page source renders `vuetify` tags (`<v-card>`) and not normal html tags. I'm just worried if this would affect anything in the future.

Comment: page source is the raw HTML as returned by the server, the javascript didn't run yet to render the component, it's fine

Comment: I see, Thank you @Saly3301!